# MySQL query to search for items with certain tags

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a MySQL database with the following tables:

```
items      | id, item
items_tags | id, item_name, item_id, tag_name, tag_id
tags       | id, tag
```

I'd like to allow the user to search for items with any tag or any combination of tags. Here's some example data to show what I'd like to do:

```
items:

id | item
-----------
1  | banana
2  | orange
3  | tomato

items_tags:

id | item_name | item_id | tag_name | tag_id
---------------------------------------------
1  | banana    | 1       | yellow   | 1
2  | banana    | 1       | fruit    | 2
3  | orange    | 2       | orange   | 3
4  | orange    | 2       | fruit    | 2
5  | tomato    | 3       | red      | 4
6  | tomato    | 3       | vegetable| 5    

tags:

id | tag
--------------
1  | yellow
2  | fruit
3  | orange
4  | red
5  | vegetable
```

What query could I run to only return items tagged with "yellow" and "fruit" (i.e., should return *row* 1 of items)?

Comment: Both `item_name` and `tag_name` are redundant on `items_tags` - the `item_id` and `tag_id` alone are sufficient to link back to the names on the parent tables.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I have item_name and tag_name in the items_tags table to make it easier for me to sift through the raw data when looking at it in an admin program (like PHPMyAdmin) during development. I plan to remove them before production.

Comment: Any idea how to exclude certain tags from the results?
i tried adding an AND NOT IN clause, with no success..

Comment: Thanks for the updated working answer. Helped me on my project using Laravel grouping tags appropriately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want the item with any of the two tag then:

```
select distinct item_id, item_name 
from items_tags 
where tag_name in ('yellow', 'fruit');
```

if you want the item having both tag then:

```
select item_id, item_name 
from items_tags 
where tag_name in ('yellow', 'fruit')
group by item_id, item_name
having count(*) = 2;
```

based on your comment

```
  select a.id, a.item 
    from items a, items_tags b, tags c 
   where a.id = b.item_id
     and b.tag_id = c.id
group by id, item
  having (group_concat(c.tag) like '%yellow%' 
         and  group_concat(c.tag) like '%fruit%')
      or group_concat(c.tag) = 'red';
```

This query gives id and item from items table. It gives item which has both yellow and fruit tag. and the items with only red tag.

if you want to get items with two tags and only two tags then use following condition in having clause

```
(group_concat(c.tag) like '%yellow%' 
and group_concat(c.tag) like '%fruit%'
and count(*) = 2)
```

Comment: This returns items tagged with either yellow or fruit or both. I want it to return only items tagged with both. Also, it returns the item_id and item_name. I'd like it to return id and item from the items table (this is obviously trivial here, but in my real database, the items table contains a lot more information than name and id that are not contained in the other tables).
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, the update is pretty much what I was looking for. Just needed to make one small adjustment so it returned what I wanted:

    `select * from items where id in 
        (select item_id 
        from items_tags 
        where tag_name in ('yellow', 'fruit')
        group by item_id
        having count(*) = 2);`

Comment: see the third query. you can adjust further more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
    Select *, count(1) as noOfTags from 
    items_tags
 group by item_id 
having  tag_name in ('yellow','fruit') and  noOfTags=2
```

Comment: Thanks! That gets me pretty close. How can I have MySQL return the matching items' rows from the table `items` instead of the rows from `items_tags`? Also, if I wanted to search for more than two tags, I obviously add another "or tag_name='tag'", but do I just increase "noOfTags=" to the number of tags I'm searching for?

Answer (score 0):

```
   Select *, count(1) as noOfTags from 
    items_tags
 group by item_id 
having  tag_name in ('yellow','fruit') and  noOfTags=2
```

yes noofTags here make sure that the item is tagged with all tags, and yes if you want to search for more tags you will add it between parentheses
Another Thing i agree with Mark about his comment,they are useless & you can use view instead it you want to get something like that (At least save some space). 
Note : I can't comment yet so i posted like answer sorry.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in one of the comments, your `items_tags` table contains a high ratio of redundant columns. For this reason, my solution skips those redundant columns.

The `group by` solution mentioned in another solution, works fine. But there may be a scenario in which a `group by` may cause problems, for example when (for whatever rare reason) the `tag` table may contain duplicated tag names.

This is a solution without the `group by`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM items i
WHERE i.id IN (
    SELECT it.item_id 
    FROM items_tags it 
    WHERE it.tag_id IN (
        SELECT t.id 
        FROM tags t 
        WHERE t.tag = 'yellow'
    )
)
AND i.id IN (
    SELECT it.item_id 
    FROM items_tags it 
    WHERE it.tag_id IN (
        SELECT t.id 
        FROM tags t 
        WHERE t.tag = 'fruit'
    )
)
```