# MySQL query to search for items with parent items tag

Tags: mysql

So I followed what they did here:
[MySQL query to search for items with certain tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519718/mysql-query-to-search-for-items-with-certain-tags)

But have an additional requirement, lets say we had the following data:

```
items:
id | item    | parent_id
------------------------
1  | banana  |  0
2  | orange  |  1
3  | tomato  |  0


items_tags:

id | item_id | tag_id
---------------------
1  | 1       | 1
2  | 1       | 2
3  | 2       | 3   
4  | 3       | 4

tags:

id | tag
--------------
1  | yellow
2  | fruit
3  | orange
4  | red
```

I am looking to run a search for items that are tagged with id 2 (fruit) and am expecting to return back item banana and orange. First is this the best way to store the information and if so what would be the most efficient query I can run to get back banana and its child orange.

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't need either `item_name` or `tag_name` in the `item_tags` table. You're already linking to the IDs in both other tables, so you can grab that information with JOINs.

Comment: U are correct, I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to store the data could be to remove the redundant columns from item_tags table (normalization):

```
items:
id | item    | parent_id
------------------------
1  | banana  |  0
2  | orange  |  1
3  | tomato  |  0

items_tags:

item_id | tag_id
------------------
1       | 1
1       | 2   
2       | 3   
3       | 4

tags:

id | tag
--------------
1  | yellow
2  | fruit
3  | orange
4  | red
```

Then your query to get the fruits, bringing only the items directly connected with the "fruit" tag, could be:

```
select items.id, items.item from items 
inner join item_tags on (items.id=item_id) 
inner join tags on (tags.id=tag_id)
where tag = 'fruit'
```

To include also items connected by parent:

```
select items.id, items.item from items 
inner join items parents on (parents.id=items.parent_id)
inner join item_tags on (item_id=items.id OR item_id=parents.id ) 
inner join tags on (tags.id=tag_id)
where tag = 'fruit'
```